# My new update is deleting databases even though the tables shouldn't be affected?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have an app on the Play Store that has a database of a couple of different types of items.

I haven't made any changes to the database for a couple of updates now, including this update I just published. When I updated using my own phone the database got wiped (during all the testing I did for this update the database was always fine).

I need help on figuring out what is happening. Why is the database being wiped when they upgrade?

Here are the relevant bits from my DatabaseHelper class:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;  //This number did not change for this update. The previous update also had 3 has the database version.
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "wines.db";

private static final String SQL_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                //some more columns in here that aren't relevant
                COLUMN_WINE_IMAGE + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_WINE_THUMBNAIL + " BLOB);";

private static final String SQL_BEER_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_BEER_NAME + " (" +
                COLUMN_BEER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                //some more columns in here that aren't relevant
                COLUMN_BEER_IMAGE + " TEXT, " +
                COLUMN_BEER_THUMBNAIL + " BLOB);";

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE);
    if (DATABASE_VERSION > 2){
        db.execSQL(SQL_BEER_CREATE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (DATABASE_VERSION < 3){
        db.execSQL(SQL_BEER_CREATE);
    }
    onCreate(db);
}
```

I don't understand during all the testing I did (multiple emulators, and my own phone using the debug version) the database was fine. Why is it that this actual Play Store update wipes the database?

Comment: I can't easily fathom out if it's the cause of your issue, but using `if (DATABASE_VERSION > 2){
        db.execSQL(SQL_BEER_CREATE);
    }` is no different to just having `db.execSQL(SQL_BEER_CREATE);` as DATABASE_VERSION will always be greater than 2 (i.e it will be 3). Likewise DATABASE_VERSION will never be < 3 as DATABASE_VERSION will always be 3. in `onCreate` you could use **`db.getVersion()`** to get the version of the database, in `onUpgrade` you could use **oldVersion** to get the current version of the database.

Comment: @MikeT Ah, yes. I did end up just removing the version checks shortly after posting this and then moving the "db.execSQL(SQL_BEER_CREATE);" to the onCreate method. This also ended up fixing the issue. I'm not still sure as to why though, since there aren't any drop table commands or anything like that.

Comment: it could be due to subsequent code expecting the BEER table to exist giving the impression that there is no data.